# Magento-adding a custom theme

Tags: magento, themes

How can I add my custom theme, but not entering directly the theme name in *System->Configuration->Design* in Administrator panel? I want to do this programmatically because of switching my app to different phases of development and I wouldn't like to enter this every time. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Assign an extra store view with your theme.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any other way of doing this without creating an extra store view?